# Is it safe to directly access superglobals with isset()?

Tags: php

I understand that one should always try to avoid direct access to superglobals to put values from superglobals into variables, eg.:

```
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name'); 
//instead of 
$name = $_POST['name']; // not safe
```

My question if it is safe to use isset() to test if a superglobal is present, eg:

```
if (isset($_POST['name')) {

}
```

I personally do not understand why this would not be good practice, but I am not that advanced in programming.

(Recently I started using Netbeans, and it gives me a tooltip recommending to change this code. Maybe the message is not entirely correct, but I would rather know for sure. I have not found a good answer anywhere else.)

Comment: What exactly does the tooltip say?

Comment: Note: your first example does not specify a filter. PHP documentation says: "If omitted, FILTER_DEFAULT will be used, which is equivalent to FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW. This will result in **no filtering taking place by default**." (emphasis mine) Lines 1 and 3 are therefore functionally equivalent - how is one of them "safe" and one of them "not safe"? I smell cargo cult.

Comment: You are right, and this actualy makes me wonder even more about the remark of Netbeans on isset(). Netbeans does not complain at all about the default filter of filter_input, which potentialy can be used in a very dangerous mannerer, while I see no harm in isset().

Comment: In the meantime I did find that it is probably better to use filter_has_var() instead of isset(), since this function is really meant for the purpose of testing is certain input variables were used.

Answer (score 3):

It is safe to use isset function in super globals. It is very effective to trigger events for a specific submit event. It only checks if the global variable is existing and will not trigger any damage such as XSS/Code/SQL injection.

I think the recommendation you received to change the code is that you need to...

```
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
```

then...

```
if (isset($name)) {
}
```

Comment: Actualy, after some extra reading, I read about the filter_has_var() function, which seems to be an even better way. http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filter_has_var.asp

Comment: Please do not omit the third argument to `filter_input`.  See @Piskvor's comment above, and conversation at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767894/warning-do-not-access-superglobal-post-array-directly-on-netbeans-7-4-for-ph.  If `name` is expected to be a string, try `$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);`

Answer (score 0):

I still am not sure whether or not there is a danger in using isset() on input variables such as $_POST. But I did find that there is a function in PHP made for just this purpose. It is the [PHP function filter_has_var()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filter_has_var.asp).
For more info on filters for input variables, I can also remommend to read more about [PHP filter functions](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_filter.asp)